# Using spinner and ArrayAdapter with Enum, setting the spinner text to an enum property

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

So I have a enum similar to...

```
package com.example.manageyobudget.model;

public enum FilingStatus {
//TODO: Would changing these texts to static or values help?
MARRIED("2:married", "Married"),
SINGLE("1:single", "Single"),
HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD("3:Head of Household", "Head of Household"),
SUPPLEMENTAL("4:Supplemental","Supplemental");

private String val;
private String text;
private FilingStatus(String val, String text){
    this.val = val;
    this.text = text;
}
public String getVal(){
    return this.val;
}
    public String getText(){
    return this.text;
}
public static String[] getTexts(){
    int count = FilingStatus.values().length;
    String[] values = new String[count];
    for(FilingStatus e : FilingStatus.values()){
        values[count--]=e.text;
    }
    return values;
}
```

}

Now I want to make a spinner I would like the ArrayAdapter to be the enums, while I want the the display text to be the values from the text property. On another I translate the value in the listener so I would assume I would need something similar to...

```
Spinner filestat = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.filestat);
filestat.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<FilingStatus>(this.getActivity(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            FilingStatus.values()));
filestat.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

But this would use the ordinal name as the value displayed in the spinner. How can I make it text property? Do I need to create a method to find enum based on Text? That seems like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just override the `toString()` method on your enum and return whatever value you would like to use as the display value.